# How to change the value of a php variable on every time page is loaded?

Tags: php

I have one variable as

```
$pwd="abcd";
```

I want this variable's value should be changed dynamically , every time this page is loaded. How to do this.

Comment: In which type...??Means randomize the string..??

Comment: yes it shoud be random string

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for random string, have a look at [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php). Likewise you have many other options in PHP Manual. It generates integer but you can use it to get a character.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for random unique value for each time

```
$pwd = md5(time() . rand(1, 1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple random string generator, you could use something like this:

```
echo substr(str_shuffle(implode(range('a','z'))), 0, 5); // 5 is the length
```

If you want to generate random numbers, then use PHP's built-in function [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand)

```
$five_digit_random_number = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
```